# How to add custom CSS of Header in Wordpress Website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to customize my header through custom css. I did the customization but I don't know how to add it in the Custom CSS section of Avada theme. Any suggestion?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Appearance/Customize/ and Additional CSS  and add example:

```
.header .fusion{
...style
}
```